# Change MTU size using netsh interface ipv4 command

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-anyconnect, mtu

I want to change the MTU size on a VPN network interface but I can't change as it says "element not found", is the command incorrect?

Type `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface`

Type `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface Local Area Connection mtu=1472`

In my case, the VPN network adapter interface name is `Ethernet 2` so how to correctly type it's name in the command code above?

[image]

Comment: In [this Microsoft forum posting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/08f3d442-3163-488d-b899-915cec25da5b/mtu-and-change-connections-mtu-limit?forum=w7itpronetworking) the interface name "Local Area Connection" is separated with backticks. I'd try that, if not working enclosing the name in single quotes.

Comment: Do not post images when plain text will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the MTU I was entering wasn't appropiate, I used lower MTU than 1182 and it worked, then I tested it and reverted back to 1182 and it let me do it. But I can not increase the MTU size to 1200 somehow.

Comment: What command did you use to lower it? What happes if you try the approach I described in my answer?

Comment: so your command worked, just with a different MTU value? Could you please add it to your answer, so it will help other users who have the same question? Did you try my approach?

Comment: @Albin as I remember it won't let me set MTU size more then 1182 but let me set lower size. This is old topic and I wans't able to increase it. Net admin fixed it by opening more corresponding ports if I remeber correctly.

Comment: I see, which command did you use to set the lower size? Did your command work or did you use my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the following 3 commands first:

```
netsh
interface
ipv4
```

the prompt should have been changed to the following: `netsh interface ipv4>`

then use the follwing command:

```
set subinterface Ethernet 2 mtu=1200 store=persistent
```

Note: you need admin rights in the CLI window, I'm using PS, not CMD